# Double MYSQL request

Tags: mysql, request, double

:)

Here's my table "chat": ID - FROM - TO - MSG - DATE - RECU

I want to list all users who chatted with $username.
Where $username is in "FROM": (line breaks added for readability)

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM chat 
        WHERE chat.from = '$username' AND chat.to != '$username' 
        GROUP BY chat.to 
        ORDER BY chat.to ASC";
```

and where $username is in "TO":

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM chat 
        WHERE chat.from != '$username' AND chat.to = '$username' 
        GROUP BY chat.from 
        ORDER BY chat.from ASC";
```

I can now list these 2 tables but how to make just one request or list just 1 table with that? DISTINCT with a UNION???

Thank you! :)

Comment: I don't see why you would need distinct, and group by doesn't make any sense, but union looks like a goo idea. Why don't you test and experiment?

Comment: I tries this but returns me a syntax error... $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT user FROM (SELECT chat.from AS user WHERE chat.to = '$username' UNION SELECT chat.to AS user WHERE chat.from  = '$username')";

Comment: you tried what? show us what you tried, and the exact and complete error you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simplifying the query somewhat; this will list usernames of all people you chatted with or chatted with you;

```
SELECT chat_from buddy FROM chat WHERE chat_to=$username
UNION
SELECT chat_to buddy FROM chat WHERE chat_from=$username
```